# How to set a popup on markers with Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

I have this code where I display and set all my markers. How can I add a popup with some information on markers with this code? I add "i" variable on text, but it sets on all markers popup with "test - 723", where 723 is last value of the "i" variable. What is wrong?

```
for (var i = 0; i < arraylng.length-1; i++) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(arraylng[i], arraylat[i])
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: " "
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent('test: ' + i + '');
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
  markers.push(marker);
}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

First, change the loop condition to `i < arraylng.length`. Right now it is not capturing the last element of your array.

JavaScript variables works with function scope so you need to call a function for each marker listener to create the correct variable references. You can use an anonymous function, [**as seen here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3059129/1238040), or define a function for creating the click listener:

Multiple infoWindows:

```
function makeInfoWindowEvent(map, infowindow, marker) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

Most likely you will not want more than one InfoWindow open at the same time, because it is annoying to have to click on the close <kbd>x</kbd>. Then you will only want one InfoWindow object, and set the content as the marker is clicked:

Single InfoWindow:

```
...
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  for (var i = 0; i < arraylng.length-1; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(arraylng[i], arraylat[i]),
      map: map
    });

    makeInfoWindowEvent(map, infowindow, "test" + i, marker);

    markers.push(marker);
  }
}

function makeInfoWindowEvent(map, infowindow, contentString, marker) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

Comment: Your jsfiddle links have expired.

Answer (score 3):

this is the area where you can add your content of popup

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: "Add your popup content here"
              });
```

and this is for showing your popup

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
```

Below code shows how its work and use.

```js
features.forEach(function(feature) {
          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: "Add your popup content here"
                  });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long),
            icon: "image.png",
            /*icon: icons[feature.type].icon,*/
            title: "Title for marker",
            map: map
          });
          marker.addListener('click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatLng,
              ....
              content: point[4]
          });
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(this.content);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
          });
```

Code inside loop. This worked for me perfectly.

Comment: Very nice and simple solution. I just tried and it works!

The only thing was missing is the declaration for `infowindow` so I added an edit to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the variable `i` is not used in the loop but when the marker is clicked -- and then i is equal to the last index + 1... The `addListener` is asynchronous, not synchronous.

Remove `infowindow.setContent('test: ' + i + '');` and replace `content: " "` with `content: 'test: ' + i`. This should fix your problem.

Comment: http://you.arenot.me/2010/06/29/google-maps-api-v3-0-multiple-markers-multiple-infowindows/ does an excellent job of explaining the solution