# How to open html popup when clicking on marker android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, maps

Hi!

How can I display a popup when clicking on a marker in google maps api android?

Here is the marker

```html
LatLng sLatLng12 = new LatLng(xx.xxxx, xx.xxxxx);
       googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(sLatLng12)
        .title(getString(R.string.title1map))
        .snippet(getString(R.string.snippet1map))
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ikon)));
```

I want to display a huge text which snippet doesn't allow me, so I want to display a popup displaying a html page or anything that can handle a huge text such as "release note" sections of other apps.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think an infowindow can help you with this. An [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows) displays content (usually text or images) in a popup window above the map, at a given location. The info window has a content area and a tapered stem. The tip of the stem is attached to a specified location on the map.

```
var contentString = "Im a pop-up";
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: contentString
});
```

Checkout this [working sample here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple).
For additional reference, see this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467070/how-to-set-a-popup-on-markers-with-google-maps-api).

Comment: thanks for your answer but I'm on android (java) not javascript. I use the InfoWindow but the Infowindow doesn't display a huge text.